# Intuitive explanation of scaled inverse chi-distribution

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, chi-squared-distribution

I am having a hard time understanding the `scaled inverse chi-distribution`. I looked for Wiki and other resources which are pretty math heavy without an intuitive explanation. Can some please explain:

1. Inverse Chi-squared distribution intuitively.
2. Importance of inverse chi-squared distribtuion.
3. A real world example to support #2